# How to host both application contract and web page (simple html page) in a WCF service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I have a WCF service host that hosts the following service binding:

```
http://localhost:2756/mywcfinterface (wshttpbinding)
```

Now I mapped this internal binding to the following domain

```
http://mywcfservice.mydomain.com
```

This works perfectly fine when connecting with a service client to that endpoint. But when I open up the address in a browser, it doesn't.

Is there a way to provide the interface to any wcf client, but a simple html website to a web browser (e.g. for informing the client).

Answer (score 1):

In order to view some information about the service contract **in a browser** (e.g. for a human), you can add a **MEX** endpoint : see msdn for [Publishing Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751951.aspx)

HTH